# Tornado future result after timeout

Tags: python, tornado, future, coroutine, concurrent.futures

This may sound a bit weird, but is it possible that Tornado completes executing a future after wrapping it in a timeout?

So something like this:

```
try:
    result = yield gen.with_timeout(time.time() + 1, future)
except gen.TimeoutError as e:
    print('Timed out!')
```

So in this scenario, `future` does not complete before timeout but I want it continue executing whatever callable it has.

To put it in a different way, I want to be able to use this along with [`gen.WaitIterator`](https://tornado.readthedocs.org/en/latest/gen.html#tornado.gen.WaitIterator) to get results of a set of futures, like described in the document:

> If you need to get the result of each future as soon as possible, or if you need the result of some futures even if others produce errors, you can use `WaitIterator`.

This is exactly what I'm looking for, I want result of each future ASAP because I have some tasks that take longer than others, but with one exception: those slow tasks should continue producing results so I can access them later.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`with_timeout` does not cancel the underlying `Future`, so it can be reused:

```
future = do_something_async()
while True:
    try:
        result = yield gen.with_timeout(timedelta(seconds=1), future)
        break
    except gen.TimeoutError:
        print('tick')
```

Combining this with `WaitIterator` is a little tricky since you must not call `WaitIterator.next` again until the previous one completes.

Also consider the Queue classes introduced in Tornado 4.2. These can often produce cleaner code than WaitIterator (and they have built-in timeout support instead of a `with_timeout` wrapper).

Comment: I guess I can use `Queue` class to aggregate results from different web services... Typically, I want to be able to collect results from different web services (some slow, some faster) and wait for all the results for a particular time. Should I be looking into Queue example (web spider) in the docs?

Also, would it be possible to `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor` instead? (since it also has [`concurrent.futures.wait`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.wait))

Comment: Yeah, the webspider demo is the best example of queue usage we have. Just put the result of each fetch on a queue and read them off in the "main" task. You can't use AsyncHTTPClient with a ThreadPoolExecutor (you could use a synchronous HTTP client but that would be more expensive than the non-threaded way).